# Angulrjs : need to help to make c3 direectives to reload data and changing chart types dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, c3.js

I am facing problem with c3 directives to reload data and changing the chart display type. Please see my plunker at http://plnkr.co/edit/wWJx3zU3Sm1cN9ZCtvoh?p=preview.

For reloading the data, I am using `$scope.refreshInData` function and for changing the chart type I am using `$scope.transform` function. But somehow these are not working. From the given example on the Github,  I tried to use transform function to change the chart type I am unable to make it work. Any help please ...

```
$scope.transform = function(filterSelected, preChartName) {
    alert('inside change Chart  ' + preChartName);
    c3SimpleService['#' + preChartName].transform(filterSelected, filterSelected);
    //  preChartName.load({ data.type : filterSelected });

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C3 transform() can take one parameter and in your case - it should.

In case of **$scope.transform** you should use it like this:

```
c3SimpleService['#' + preChartName].transform(filterSelected.value);
```

notice 2 things:

1. transform takes 1 parameter and it is string - name of chart type
2. what you are passing is object, so you have to access its **value** field

As for **$scope.refreshInData()** problem is slightly different. Here only thing you have to fix is to grab chart not with it's ID directly, but through **c3SimpleService** service. This will allow access through AngularJS layer:

```
c3SimpleService['#' + preChartName].load({ columns : cityData });
```

You can see it working in [Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/q6qQHd2vB54WNwPNxET3?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks Wasil, but I noticed a problem with refreshInData function. When I change that dropdown even though the new data is getting loaded (dR, yu, iyt) but the old data (FedEx, UPS, DHL) also remaining as it is. Even the old labels (FedEx, UPS and DHL) are remaining as it is. When the new data is loaded all the old data and labels should be replaced with new data  and labels, how can I achieve it?

Comment: I mean the chart should be generated with new data only upon the dropdown change.

Comment: Try using _unload()_ method from C3.js [API](http://c3js.org/reference.html). It allows you to unload specific data series, i.e. "DHL" when loading a new one. There is also an example provided [here](http://c3js.org/samples/data_load.html)

Comment: Perfect. Accepting the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an scope variable like : isChart its value true/false. You can use this scope into your ng-if condition. on every request/change you need to change its false after request success make it true. and also you need to reset you graph data array on every change/request. it works perfectlly.